# including a file from outside wp-content folder in my plugin file

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently created a custom wordpress plugin that lives within wp-content/plugins folder. I also created another folder named *players* that is at the same level as wp-content. I am trying to reference a file from players folder (players-client.php) into my custom plugin file. I have tried various ways but keep getting errors.

Here is a visual structure of the folders/files:

players
-> players-client.php
wp-admin
wp-content
-> plugins
-----> custom-plugin folder
---------> my-plugin.php
wp-includes

This is how my absolute path is defined:
`if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {   define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' ); }`

When i try to `echo ABSPATH;`
This is what i get: `/var/www/html/` and i am running is on localhost.

I tried in my-plugin.php: `require_once ABSPATH . 'players/players-client.php`;

but when i reload my site it breaks stating an error occurred.

Based on the folder/file structure that i have - how can i properly reference players-client.php from my-plugin.php.

Comment: Where is `ABSPATH`?

Comment: WordPress has two constants that you might find useful, `WP_CONTENT_DIR` and `WP_CONTENT_URL`

Comment: You didn't mention, what is the error to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: @VijayHardaha the error as i stated is the path i am calling the file is breaking the site. Based on the file structure that i have how can i properly call from a child file up to another parent folder.

Comment: It's hard to say something without knowing the actual error message. but if your callable file exists and there is no typo in the file and dir name. then please check for the file permissions, and make sure it has the correct permission.